# PhpStorm suggest MySQL database column name

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

I am interested in how to do MySQL column name suggestion.

Here is my simple database.

[image: Here is my simple database.]

This is my php code in `route/web.php`

[image]

This is my `about.blade.php` file

[image]

I want it to suggest me MySQL column name like `id`, `body`, `created_as`, `update_at`.. like this `$task->...` and here to suggest me all the column names which has table.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes and No. **No** -- there is no such functionality that would do it automatically. But **Yes** -- you may try via intermediate fake class (used by IDE only) that will have all such fields defined .. and then type hint `$task` in your blade template with that class via PHPDoc (should be working in current EAP builds of 2017.1). Yeah .. requires quite a bit of writing...

Comment: So .. you may try submitting Feature Request to PhpStorm's [Laravel plugin authors](https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-laravel-plugin/issues) -- maybe they can implement such Laravel-specific functionality so it can be used with less effort.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of.

However, you wouldn't be able to use the DB class, you'd need to create a Model and create the appropriate `@property` tags in the docblock.

Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't I have noticed.  It really depends if PHPStorm picks up the proper context.  It likely won't be picked up automatically in blade templates but you can type hint any variable:

```
/** @var TaskModel $task */
```

There is a good plugin for IDE autocompletion with regards to Laravel here: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper